# Data output from the device

Tags: c, webots

I am working on a project,in which I need to extract data from the device: InertialUnit. 
I get a single value in real time, but I need data for the first 10 s and in 1 ms increments, or all the data for the entire cycle of the device. Please help me implement this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webots controllers are like any other programs, so you can easily get the values of the inertial unit and save them in a file at each step.
Here is a very simple example in Python:

```
from controller import Robot

robot = Robot()


inertial_unit = robot.getInertialUnit('inertial unit')
inertial_unit.enable(10)

while robot.step(10) != -1:
    values = inertial_unit.getValues()
    with open('values.txt','a') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(values))
```

Comment: Please tell me if I wrote correctly?                                                                                                    inertial_unit = wb_robot_get_device("iu");
wb_inertial_unit_enable(inertial_unit, 10);                                                                               
const double *value = wb_inertial_unit_get_roll_pitch_yaw(inertial_unit);
fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Dicipy\\Desktop\\values.txt", "at");                                          
fprintf(fp, "device value is %f %f %f\n", value[0], value[1], value[2]);                       fclose(fp);

Comment: That looks indeed correct. But don't forget the while (wb_robot_step()) loop.